# How do we add different nameserver to subdomain created under WIX panel

Tags: dns

I need to run my main website (e.g abc.com) on wix and subdomain (e.g shop.abc.com) on different server. Hence want to connect different nameserver to subdomain, how we can do this?

there is no such option we get to map different nameserver to subdomain apart from parent website nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

How to add subdomain to Wix?
To connect a subdomain to your Wix site:
Go to Domains ﻿in your Wix account.
Click Connect a domain you already own. ...
Select the site you want to connect and click Next.
Enter the subdomain you want to connect (e.g., blog.mystunningwebsite.com).
Click Let's Go.
Follow the steps according to your domain connection type:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).